# Pid after fork in C

Tags: c, linux, fork

I scripted this simple code in C to emulate what happens after a fork in Linux

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int value = 5;
int main()
{
    pid t pid;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) { /* child process */
        value += 15;
        return 0;
    }
    else if (pid > 0) { /* parent process */
        wait(NULL);
        printf("PARENT: value = %d",value); /* LINE A */
        return 0;
    }
}
```

It works, even if i dont understand how the fork() succed in giving different PIDs to parent and child processes. Is it connected to the "shared memory segment" beetween parent and child processes ?
Can you explain me ?

Comment: It seems that you are going too fast. You are implying that it should not work because you don't understand it. Slow down, go with more basic concepts and then try and learn `fork()` and/or threading.

Comment: `fork()` invokes functionality of the OS kernel. The kernel duplicates the process, assigns an unused ID to the new process and makes `fork()` return different values in the two processes. Apart from their parent-child relationship managed by the kernel, the two processes are separate and run independent of each other. There is no *"shared memory segment"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a successful call to `fork`, a new process is created which is an exact duplicate of the calling process.  So the function actually returns twice, once to the parent and once to the child, with the parent's return value being the PID of the child and the child's return value being 0.

The new process does not however share data with the parent.  All constructs, including the stack and global variables, are distinct from those in the parent.

In this case, the child process adds 15 to `value`.  This variable is however completely separate from `value` in the parent process.  So when the parent prints `value`, it prints the value that the parent has, which is 5.